# Why aren't textures appearing in viewport render but visible in the final render?

Tags: rendering, texturing, objects, 3d-view, shaders

I'm messing around with the [Barcelona Pavillion demo scene](https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/). When I enable the viewport render, no textures are appearing in the viewport render, the objects are just grey:

[image]

However, when I render the scene all the textures are properly assigned. Why is this?

Comment: can you provide blend file?

Comment: https://download.blender.org/demo/test/pabellon_barcelona_v1.scene_.zip

Answer (score 4):

In the *View Layers* panel > *Override*, remove the selected material, otherwise you'll make it the only one showing for all your objects:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the "viewport shading" view normally there are no textures. This is default behaviour (there are exceptions). If you want to see textures, change to

- material preview [image]

or

- rendered view [image]

The "solid" viewport display is made for building/moving/creating things and good performance. That's why textures aren't shown because they tend to make the computer/visualization slower.

Comment: Yes, but I'm in the "render view' mode, using cycles. Normally, I can see textures in this view, but for some reason, I cannot on this file.

Comment: ok, that's weird. I can see it...what version are u using?

Comment: The most recent version. 2.92 I think. I'm pretty sure It's a setting specific to this file, as none of my personal .blends do this.

Comment: Ok, that’s even more weird. Did you try to download the file again? Maybe you changed something unintentionally?

Comment: No, I believe this is just how the author made it. Must be a setting somewhere. Anyway, I was just curious. Thanks for the help anyways.